# Run python script without calling the interpreter

Tags: python, linux, path, interpreter

I am facing some difficulties running my python script without the "Python" keyword at the beginning.
I've tried several suggestions already from similar questions, but none of them worked :

- using `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of the script didn't help me as suggested in other places. I'm getting the following error:

  > : No such file or directory
- changed file and folder permissions :

  > ls -la script.py
  >
  > -rwxrwxrwx 1 myuser g 24528 Apr  7 01:25 script.py
- tried to use `#!/usr/bin/python2.7 -B` but got the following error when trying to execute :

  > Unknown option: -
  >
  > usage: /usr/intel/bin/python2.7 [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
  >   Try `python -h' for more information.

I can't figure it out why I'm not able to run the script just as it is **./script.py**, and not calling python interpreter manually at the beginning.

Comment: What error did you get with the first one? That should work fine, assuming you have `/usr/bin/env` and `python` is in your path.

Comment: It's worth noting you need **both** the shebang and the execute flag.

Comment: When I use /usr/bin/env python , I get this error message when executing  " : No such file or directory"

Comment: Your file has CRLF line endings. Use `dos2unix script.py` to fix it.

Comment: Amazing! , couldn't find a solution for this anywhere, I'm sure it will help others as well. Thank you for that.